# Listing users by certain string, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to figure out how to list my users by a certain string. In my app I have `Artist` who have one `Artist_profile` through `has_one`. In my `Artist_profile`, I have `genre`, which is what I'm trying to sort them out by. I do have it working at the moment with an if statement, but it looks through every single `Artist` and picks out the ones with the match. For example:

```
<% @artists.each do |artist| if artist.artist_profile.genre == "Rock" %>
  <li><%= artist.id %></li>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to get it something more like this, so it's less strain on my database:

```
<% @artists.rock.each do |artist| %>
  <li><%= artist.id %></li>
<% end %>
```

and my model:

```
def self.rock
  where(Artist.artist_profile.genre == "Rock")
end
```

However I get this error:

```
undefined method `artist_profile' for #<Class:0x6962940>
```

I think it's something to do with the `has_one` method, but can't seem to get this to work no matter what I try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Joins](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins) method. It allows you to search fields in associated models. This differs from the [Includes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) method as the Joins method doesn't include the results in the data. For example, if you wanted to list the artist genre instead of the id, then you would want to use Includes. In your code, you should put:

```
@artists = Artist.joins(:artist_profile).where("artist_profiles.genre" => "Rock")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call scope as `Artist.artist_profile`, it's an instance method

You can defind scope `rock` in `ArtistProfile` model

The result will look like this

```
class ArtistProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  scope :rock, ->{where(genre: "Rock")}
  ...
```

and use it:

```
@rock_profiles = ArtistProfile.rock
<% @rock_profiles.each do |profile| %>
  <li><%= profile.artist_id %></li>
<% end %>
```